# RelativeLayout child won't align Right?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

This is the code I am using to try and align a child to the right of the parent element why isn't this code working?

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();

RelativeLayout headingEnd = new RelativeLayout(this.context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams headingEndParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams headingEndTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
headingEnd.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
headingEnd.setId(1);
headingEnd.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
headingEndParams.width = 200;
headingEndParams.height = 50;
headingEndParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END,-1);

headingEnd.addView(headingEnd, headingEndParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the anchor id is missing. Instead of

```
headingEndParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END,-1);
```

I would try

```
headingEndParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END,R.id.idOfViewWhichShouldBeAlignedAtParent);
```

This is just an idea.

Comment: The thing I never use XML to style the page.. so there is no R.id variables.

Comment: No prob. You can define a resource for this: <item type="id" name="myViewId" /> and the set the id on the view using setId(R.id.myViewId) method.